# How to avoid viber popup to get focus of my android Application programmatically?

Tags: android, socket.io, popup, viber

I have an Android application that use SocketIO to have communication with its server. It continuously sends Heart bit to a server in order to show, the application is running.
The problem is that when a message on viber revived, viber popup showed and get the focus of my application, so the application go to suspend mode and can't send Heart bit and server close the socket. 
Now, How can I avoid viber to show it's popup on top of my application?
Or How to close the popup quickly?
Or How to avoid viber to get the focus of my application?

[image]

Comment: This does not answer your question, but you should be sending heartbeat in na background service, this way the heartbeat signal is not interrupted by viber or any other application poping up.

Answer (score 1):

Restart app every 1 minute (with intent) to get focus back.